# Invalid block tag on line 3: 'raw'. Did you forget to register or load this tag? with Django 1.9 and Jinja2

Tags: django, jinja2

I am a beginner in Django 1.9 and Jinja2. I have been trying to implement Jinja2 in Django 1.9, but I keep receiving the error as below:

Invalid block tag on line 2: 'raw'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

The code that giving problem is:

```
{%raw%}<form {{action "login" on="submit"}}>{%endraw%}
```

I have checked the settings.py, but I am not sure where did I do wrongly:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(EMBER_DIR, 'templates')
    ],
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
            # list if you haven't customized them:
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
            'django.template.context_processors.static',
            'django.template.context_processors.tz',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
   },
 },
 {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'DIRS': [],
},]
```

Edit

I have solved this issue by downgrade the Django to 1.8.8 and use Django-Jinja.

Thanks for the help guys :)

Comment: Please show the full traceback. What is the template name? Is it being rendered by the Django template engine or the Jinja template engine?

Comment: What is the path to your jinja templates?

Answer (score 3):

The format of your block is wrong. Use this instead:

```
{% block raw %} {% endblock %}
```

According with the documentation, more information [here](https://realpython.com/blog/python/primer-on-jinja-templating/).

Comment: Hey Luan, thanks for your reply. But the page shows 

"Could not parse the remainder: ' "login" on="submit"' from 'action "login" on="submit"'

After I modify it to your {% block raw %} {% endblock%}. I have tried with 
{% block raw %} {% endblock raw%} as well. No luck :(

Comment: The problems now is because you are putting {{action "login" on="submit"}}.  I wonder if better  if you use this way : <form action ="login" onsubmit="{{YourMethod}}">